# Having Issue on Passing String From Controller to View in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having issue on passing `string` parameter from controller to view in the controller I have:

```
namespace Map02.Controllers
{
    public class AppController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index(string name)
        {
            string str = name;
            return View(str);
        }

    }
}
```

and in view I have:

```
@model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}

<h2>AppContent</h2>

<p>@str</p>
```

but I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Change `@str` to `@Model`

Comment: You also need to use `return View((object)str);` otherwise it will try to find a view that matches `str`

Comment: Hi Frahad, thanks for reply I am not getting any error now but I am not still getting the output either.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I update the `return View((object)str);` but not getting any output in page!

Comment: Then it means the value of `name` is `null`

Comment: but I am passing `http://localhost:50095/Files/Map/File` to URL so I am passing the `File` ! am I right?

Comment: And do you have a specific route defined for that url (if you only have the default route then it would need to be `public ActionResult Index(string id)` (and I'm assuming `Index` is a typo and its really `Map` if that's the url your calling)

Comment: You can use **Viewbag** if you passing just a string.

Answer (score 4):

To pass a string to the view as the Model, you can do:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string str = name;;
    return View((object)str);
}
```

You must cast it to an object so that MVC doesn't try to load the string as the view name, but instead pass it as the model. You could also write:

```
return View("Index", str);
```

Then in your view, just type it as a string:

```
 @model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}

<h2>AppContent</h2>

<p>@Model</p>
```

Comment: Important : You have to change <p>@str</p> to <p>@Model</p>

Comment: `return View("Index", str);` does not work! (its calling [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.String%29)

Comment: I think this will work 
return View("Index",(object)str);

Comment: Yes it will, but that's identical to `return View((object)str);` so its a bit pointless :)